# Create Secret Scope failed - Unable to grant read/list permission to Databricks service principal

Tags: azure-databricks

I try to create scope, but getting error. My Azure user account have permission for Subscription "owner" and "Key Vault Contributor" for this Key Vault. My user account have Get, List, Set rights to Secrets and Keys of Key Vault. What could be wrong?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes

```
Unable to grant read/list permission to Databricks service principal to KeyVault 'https://mysecrets- 
test.vault.azure.net/': Status code 403, {"odata.error": 
{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to 
complete the operation."},"requestId":"33331e84-a7dd-43b3-a548-147dcf14e31e","date":"2020-11- 
26T14:37:17"}}
```

Comment: I added secret/key permission for AzureDatabricks service principal, error is still same.